# How can I display a blog post content and delete it using my modal in django?

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal

I have created a bootstrap modal for my blog home page in django which I would like to use to delete posts and also show the post content prior to deleting.

My html to trigger the modal looks like this:

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

Then my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="delete" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Do you really want to delete?</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <a href="{% url 'post_delete' post.id %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-outline">Yes, Delete</a>
                    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My views.py file looks like this:

```
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog_home')
```

My urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='stream_home'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post_create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
]
```

And my models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    dislikes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content[:5]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Upon attempting to load the page I am shown this error:

```
Reverse for 'post_delete' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete/$']
```

If I remove the delete button the page loads and the modal shows up on click but my {{ post.content }} tag fails to display. Please help...

Comment: Can you post the models.py as well

Comment: Sure. Updated to show models

Comment: It looks likes it not finding your post object. Is the post id showing up in the url?

Comment: I am only receiving a NoReverseMatch so I cannot even see the url. But I believe you're right, the modal is not recognizing the object. I have tried relocating the href to the modal trigger button, however this only led to more weird errors

Comment: check to see if your post object exists in the django admin or in your database. Can you see it in your listview or update view?

Comment: Yes the object does exist. I can update it, and before I created the modal I was able to link to another page in order to delete it. So I believe the problem must reside within the modal...

Answer (score 1):

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView), I think you need to use a form for the DeleteView

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are you sure you want to delete?</p>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-outline" value="Yes, Delete">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary btn-outline">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

That button doesn't seem to be doing anything. Maybe change it to link it back to the Listview or something

Comment: Thanks, still not working. I am still receiving the same message :-(

Comment: It looks like you don't have 'post_detail' (in the get_absolute_url method in your model) defined in your urls and possibly your views as well

Comment: I have solved the issue. My modal was contained outside the for loop of my blog posts. All works now! Thank you so much for your help